# cache Javascripts in different views - under same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a few JavaScript that I would like to cache as follow :

layout1.erb has

```
.........
  <%=  javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min' ,
    'rails_ujs',
    'qwerty',
    'jquery_editinplace',
    'jquery.livequery',
    'jquery.validate',
    'ddsmoothmenu',
    :cache=>"main_js_cache"
%>
..........
```

layout2.erb

```
.........
  <%=  javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min' ,
    'rails_ujs',
    'qwerty',
    'jquery_editinplace',
    'jquery.livequery',
    'jquery.validate',
    'ddsmoothmenu',
    :cache=>"main_js_cache"
%>
..........
```

Now since the cache file name is same would the same be used or will it be generated again & again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer..
Left the question open incase others find it useful..

This is how caching goes..

First time suppose you render `layout2.erb` .. then it combines and generates a file called as `"main_js_cache"`.

Next time you again render `layout2.erb` then it will just directly throw `"main_js_cache"` without regenerating it.

Suppose you render `layout1.ebr` in that case rails just looks for a file called `"main_js_cache"` it finds it and so it does **NOT** generate a new file.